# JQUERY / ASP.NET: Reshowing the jquery dialog after an asp.net occurs?

Tags: asp.net, jquery, events, jquery-ui, postback

Can anyone tell me the easiest way to display a jQuery dialogafter a postback occurs.

Basically i am showing some asp.net controls inside my jQuery dialog and when i click something an event occurs in asp.net

But of course after the postback has finished the screen is brought back up but WITHOUT the jQuery dialog..  This is by design I presume but wondered if there was a way around this?

I am using the updatepanel (asp.net).

Any ideas really appreciated?

Thanks

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You could use the `ScriptManager.RegisterStartupScript` to load the popup. See [documentation](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb359558.aspx)

Comment: Great! It works a treat although there is a postback of course